# Extra field coming in get response in spring boot application

Tags: spring

In my spring boot application I have booking controller which has corresponding service,repository and controller.
My booking Model looks like this :

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "datetime")// corresponds to value 
private Date date;
public Date getDatetime() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.date = dateTime;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("api/booking_details/{userEmail}")
    @ResponseBody
    public  ResponseEntity<List<Booking>>  getDetails(
         
            @PathVariable @Email String userEmail) {
 
            return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.findByEmail(userEmail), HttpStatus.OK);

     }
```

My corresponding get request is

```
api/booking_details/
```

the response I am getting is :

```
     {
     "datetime": "2021-09-12T16:01:04.000+00:00",
       "date": "2021-09-12"
      }
```

Can any one let me know what could be reason for having two values in response?

Comment: Where's the controller?

Comment: Added the controller code too

Comment: You have two attributes in Booking.java, date and datetime, am I wrong?

Comment: No only one attribute but in response it is returning as two values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is getter and setter method are not identified as `date parameter's` getter and setter methods. Two things you can do,

Rename getter and setter method name as follows,

```
public Date getDate() {
    return this.date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

Or annotate getter and setter method using `@JsonProperty("date")` annotation. Added this annotation for only getter method is also sufficient.

```
@JsonProperty("date")
public Date getDatetime() {
    return this.date;
}

@JsonProperty("date")
public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
    this.date = dateTime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue.You saved me !!!

Comment: Glad to help you! Please leave a vote!  : )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both the "date" property and the return value of the getDateTime() method are being serialized.

I wouldn't normally expect the "date" property, which is private, to get serialzied, but perhaps it is because you have the @JsonFormat annotation on it?

The getDateTIme() return value is serialized because it's name indicates that it's a Java Bean property.

If what you are looking for is just the formatted date, I'd try moving the @JsonFormat annotation to the method.